# jQuery Mobile - Links and Radio buttons in Accordion not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I have a site [here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/mil-test.html#armyActive).

When you get there, click on **Student Instructions** and then hit the **Help** button. When it tries to go to that document (a PDF on the server), the page comes up undefined... but the URL to the document is correct. When I refresh the page, then it takes me to the document.

Why does it do that?

**Here's the snippet from that part of the page...**

```
    <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="d">

        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3><img src="images/gear.png" style="vertical-align: middle; ">Student Instructions...</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>+ Create a GoArmyEd Account. <a href="docs/TA- GoArmyEd-LOI-Walkthrough-SUO-2-15-13.pdf"><span style="font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">Need a walkthrough?</span><img src="images/walkthrough.png" style="vertical-align: middle;"></a></li><br>
                        <li>+ Print Statement of Understanding (South University) and have it signed by their Commander.</li><br>
                        <li>+ Receive Cost Verification worksheet (CVWS) and Degree Progress Audit (DPA).</li><br>
                        <li>+ Upload all documents into GoArmyEd.</li><br>
                        <li>+ Apply for Tuition Assistance.</li>

                    </ul>
        </div>
```

**Also**, you'll notice that when you back to the original page, there are several radio buttons that appear clicked. I used the jQuery radio button layout because I like it... I just don't know how to make those button clicks go away. It looks terrible.

Thoughts?

**Update** - I tried adding `rel="external"`, `data-ajax="false"` separately and together. I'm able to open the document when I right-click and "Open link in a new tab"... Still doesn't open onclick though.

**Update 2** - Tried adding the following, but it disabled my entire style sheet.

```
<script>
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled(false);
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple with google `embed` document.

1) create your link to that page as usual'
2) on the destination page add this     iframe

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://yoursite.com/folderWhereYouHideYourPdfFile/yourPdfFile.pdf&embedded=true" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0">
```

this will embed the document.
you can then style it up. 
if you want, can be  to popup or load with ajax.

=============================Another Method Could be to use Php==============
So Instead of iframe on destination page you can have something like this

```
<?php
$filePdf = 'yourPdfFile.pdf';
$fileTitle = 'Become A Solider'; 

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $fileTitle . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePdf));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

@readfile($filePdf);
?>
```

Comment: Hi again! Please have a look at this link [here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/mil-test.html#topUp) and you'll see where I've got the iframe running... however, I'm trying to resize it and it's not working out in my favor. Any ideas here? Additionally, the iframe has a left margin of almost 50%. I've played around with the code in Chrome, but can't seem to get the desired result. Thoughts?

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. I added a style tag to the html.