# Laravel routing: How to create a link to a PDF file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I need to generate PDF documents and have them send by email as well as make them reachable by a link.
Sending by email is OK, but I have no idea how to create the link.

Since I use Laravel 4, all links are going through `routes.php`.
So how do I create a link to a file at a given directory?

```
<a href="http://my.domain.org/assets/pdf/file.pdf">Link</a>
```

will not work, since the route is not known by laravel...

Comment: I have answer for you 

[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412680/jquery-mobile-links-and-radio-buttons-in-accordion-not-working/18412960#18412960)

this how do this

Comment: If you put your PDF file in your public directory you can create a direct link, did you tried it?

Answer (score 10):

To generate a link to a physical file or directory, that you don't want to run through Laravel's application (e.g. through index.php), use `URL::asset()`.

```
URL::asset('assets/pdf/file.pdf');
```

This assumes you've created a physical PDF file on your server that you want to link to. If your PDF file is dynamic and generated/retrieved through your Laravel application, you should use `URL::to()`, `URL::route()`, or similar.

Comment: how can i do it in laravel-5.3

Comment: Aken is correct. You just need to wrap his response in an a tag:

```<a href="{{ URL::asset('/route/to/pdf/file.pdf') }}">Click Here To Go To PDF</a>```

This is the simplest way to display a pdf.

Answer (score 5):

Martin Tale is right, but this is another way of accomplishing the same using Laravel's Blade:

```
{{ link_to('/assets/pdf/file.pdf', 'Link') }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create that PDF somewhere in public directory and then create a link to that file like this:

```
URL::to('path/to/public/directory/file.pdf')
```

Comment: OK, this brings up an "Class 'URL' not found" error - probably, because my test.php is not using laravel but is stored within the public directory of a laravel app...

Comment: tried that but I dont know why it gets downloaded automatically

Answer (score 0):

if you are using laravel 4's MAIL feature you can add this to it

```
$message->attach($pathToFile);
```

but the .pdf in your public directory under a pdf folder and that will make it:

```
$message->attach('pdf/mypdffile.pdf');
```

the same can be for a link which you can add to the email

```
{{ URL::to('pdf/mypdffile.pdf') }}
```

You shouldn't need a route to create a link it can be done by blade.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, in a view:

```
<a href="{{ asset('/your_pdf_file.pdf') }}">some text</a>
```

This link will go to `public` folder.